# Как кинуть текущий год в содержимое тега?

Tags: javascript

Как кинуть текущий год в содержимое тега?
текущий год могу найти а как кинуть не получается

```js
// текущая дата
var date = document.getElementsByClassName('.year_box');
date = new Date();
// var date = new Date();

// час в текущей временной зоне
var year_box = (date.getYear() - 100 + 2000);
```

```html
<div class="year_box" style="color: red;"></div>
```

Comment: Ворнинг: на данный момент ответы ниже верны, но не учитывают что DOM может ещё не быть готов.

Comment: @Other, можно поподробней?

Comment: @Air, можно: если скрипт добавления будет выполнен до построения DOM (в начале страницы, например, и без обёртки в callback на событие загрузки (e. g. `DOMContentLoaded`)), то поиск в документе ничего не найдёт, хотя тэг там есть, просто он ещё не загружен. Частая ошибка новичка.

Comment: @Other, не могу с тобой не согласиться)))) Я понял о чем ты.  Но не думаю, что это столь важно ,  для человека, который выбрал для себя вариант ответа,  с методом, который не входит уже в спецификацию JS.......)))))  Но ты прав на все сто... И если быть откровенным до конца, когда отвечал, я с твоей точки зрения вообще не рассматривал...  Благодарю,

Comment: @Air, никогда не поздно научится :)

Comment: @Other, друг мой, )))  кому ты рассказываешь, я JS в августе изучать, а верстать всего то 3 года назад...  Не знаю сколько тебе, а мне достаточно много))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.year_box').innerText = (new Date).getFullYear();
```

```html
<div class="year_box"></div>
```

Comment: Просто и лаконично ;)

Answer (score 1):

`.getYear()`-  уже давно устарел. Используй `getFullYear()`

```js
var date = new Date();
document.getElementsByClassName('year_box')[0].innerHTML = date.getFullYear();
```

```html
<div class="year_box" style="color: red;"></div>
```